# Footer value is printing the same data inside foreach in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I have an array data which I'm trying to print in my blade view using foreach loop . But here my condition is i need to print the bundle name and total only one time inside table .
Array data :

```
$data =  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [asset_name] => Mini Paver
            [qty] => 2
            [days] => 5
            [bundle_name] => Bundle 1
            [total] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [asset_name] => Roller
            [qty] => 2
            [days] => 5
            [bundle_name] => Bundle 1
            [total] => 1000
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [asset_name] => Medi Paver
            [qty] => 2
            [days] => 5
            [bundle_name] => Bundle 2
            [total] => 2000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [asset_name] => Sweet Roller
            [qty] => 2
            [days] => 5
            [bundle_name] => Bundle 2
            [total] => 2000
        )
)
```

Blade view code:

```
@php ($bundle_name = false)
@foreach($data as $value) 
    @if($bundle_name != $value['bundle_name'])
        @if($bundle_name != false)
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="4"> <p> Total : {{ $value['total'] }} </p></th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        </table> 
        @endif
    @php ($bundle_name = $value['bundle_name'])
    <table class="" style="width: 100%;border:1px solid #ccc">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4"> <p> {{ $bundle_name }} </p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center">id</th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Asset Category</th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Days</th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    @endif
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center">{{ $value['id'] }} </th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">{{ $value['asset_name'] }}</th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">{{ $value['days'] }}</th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">{{ $value['qty'] }}</th>
            </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th colspan="4"> <p> Total : {{ $value['total'] }} </p></th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Currently I'm getting the view like below in the picture 
[image]

But i need the result view should be as like this :
[image]

Here i dont want to add the total , it should display same like bundle_name. 
Can some one help me  to solve this ? Thank you !

Comment: Why are you starting content with `</tbody>` ? Should it be `<tbody>` ?

Comment: @Sagar Gautam  :  Actually i m not starting with `</tbody>` I m ending there '</tbody>' if `$bundle_name != false`  . Please help me if you have any other way to solve this ?

Comment: After this line  `@if($bundle_name != false)` you have `<\tbody>` look again before `<tfoot>` . Is it typo or for some reason

Comment: Yes i have but if i remove that , Total is  only not displaying

Comment: Sorry, you have wrongly thought what I've said. Look at 5th line in above question's Blade view code:

Comment: Yeah that is what i m telling , at 5th line i m checking the condition and then closing it i remove the code from there its collapsing the table view .

Comment: Did you solve the problem or not ? i have a solution for you witout changing your logic !

Comment: @Maraboc : nope . Please suggest me your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution, i'm not chaging your solution here :) :

```
@php ($bundle_name = false)
@php ($total_value = 0)
@foreach($data as $value) 
    @if($bundle_name != $value['bundle_name'])
        @if($bundle_name != false)
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
            <th colspan="4"> <p> Total : {{ $total_value }} </p></th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </table> 
        @endif
        @php ($bundle_name = $value['bundle_name'])
        <table class="" style="width: 100%;border:1px solid #ccc">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4"> <p> {{ $bundle_name }} </p></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center">id</th>
                    <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Asset Category</th>
                    <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Days</th>
                    <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Qty</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    @endif
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center">{{ $value['id'] }} </th>
            <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">{{ $value['asset_name'] }}</th>
            <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">{{ $value['days'] }}</th>
            <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">{{ $value['qty'] }}</th>
        </tr>
    @php ($total_value = $value['total'])
@endforeach
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th colspan="4"> <p> Total : {{ $total_value }} </p></th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Okay let me try this

Comment: Happy to help ;)